# macOS, "touching" OneDrive folder forces it to re-sync

Tags: objective-c, macos, synchronization, onedrive

need your help with OneDrive folders sync process while scanning those folders.

Developing our own solution that is scanning Mac we've just faced an issue where scanning the OneDrive folder forces the service to re-sync all the files with the server.

We are using several calls to the location, scanning it, exactly these two (ObjC):

`MDItemRef item = MDItemCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)anItemPath);`

and
`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:path]`

Do you know if there any solutions, like ignore list, APIs, or any similar that won't cause files re-sync?

Thanks!